# Does post-data requires single quotes around the json-object in ajax/post request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple post request to a directions API using ajax/post. i'm struggeling with getting the right format for the data-field in the post-request.

When leaving out the the single quote around the data-field it becomes invalid. And i get a bad-request message from the API. Ive tried to use stringify but i'm still not getting the quotes around the entire object.I'm clearly missing something here !

```
**//This would throw an error for malformed json**
let postData = {"locations": ["antwerpen", "zaventem"],"options": 
               {"routeType": "fastest"}};

**//This would work just fine**
let postData = '{"locations": ["antwerpen", "zaventem"],"options": 
               {"routeType": "fastest"}}';

$.post({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    'https://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=$key',
    data:   postData,
    success: function(data) {
        let response    = data;
        let afstand     = response.route.distance;
    },
    contentType:    "application/json",
    dataType:       'json'
});
```

I have no ideo where to look, is this a json thing or rather a javascript issue, as you can tell i'm not that good at js ! The locations are fed by user input and let postData is accomplished by using json.stringify

Comment: `const postData = JSON.stringify({....});`

Comment: Your JSON.stringify should work just fine. What error are you getting?. Moreover when you are using `$.post` , there is no need to specify a type parameter separately

Comment: @Keith , Thats exactly what i needed ! thanks for taking your time to read / answer my question.

Comment: `Ive tried to use stringify but i'm still not getting the quotes around the entire object.` And here I thought you had already tried that

Comment: Just for completeness: in case you want to use double-quotes inside a double-quoted string, escape it via backslash: `"I am in \"quotes\""`. Same applies if you want to escape single-quotes inside a single-quoted string.